# How to pass enum definition through a function and access its members there in java?

Tags: java, enums

I am using mongodb and for data validation I am trying to use java enums. I have defined db schema in enum and trying to pass that enum and the actual data through the validationFunction.

Enum definition is given below.

```
//Enum definition
public enum Type {
  STRING, OBJECT, INTEGER    
}

public enum Existence {
  REQUIRED, OPTIONAL
}

public enum Adress {
  HOUSE_NO("houseNo", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED),
  STREET_NO("streetNo", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED),
  LANDMARK("landmark", Type.STRING, Existence.OPTIONAL)
      public enum employeeSchema {
  NAME("name", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED),
  AGE("age", Type.INTEGER, Existence.Optional),
  ADDRESS("address", Type.OBJECT, Existence.REQUIRED)

  String text;
  Type valueType;
  Existence exist;
  Address(String text, Type valueType, Existence exist) {
    this.text = text;
    this.valueType = valueType;
    this.exist = exist;
  }
}

public enum employeeSchema {
  NAME("name", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED),
  AGE("age", Type.INTEGER, Existence.Optional),
  ADDRESS("address", Type.OBJECT, Existence.REQUIRED, Address)

  String text;
  Type valueType;
  Existence exist;
  employeeSchema(String text, Type valueType, Existence exist) {
    this.text = text;
    this.valueType = valueType;
    this.exist = exist;
  }
  employeeSchema(String text, Type valueType, Existence exist, Enum schema) {
    this.text = text;
    this.valueType = valueType;
    this.exist = exist;
    this.schema = schema;
  }
}
```

Now I want to pass employeeSchema through a function to validate the data.

```
public boolean validateData(JsonNode data, Enum schema){
  //Want to iterate the enum here. Get the corresponding field from the data and will check if the field has type required and if its null it will return false. Again if the field would be object this function would be called with respective schema.
}
```

So the problem is, I want to pass enum through the function, but need to have generic return type because when I am collecting it in Enum type it does not have the respective enum values.

For example, if I pass employeeSchema and do employeeSchema.text it says Enum type does not have text.

I hope my problem is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My ideas about your code are the following:

1. Make `Type` a class and merge it with `schema` field.
2. Make the interface like `Field` and make all enums implement it:

Here's the `Field` interface:

```
public interface Field {
    String getText();
    Type getType();
    Existence getExistence();
}
```

Here's updated `Type` class:

```
public static final class Type {
    // predefined primitive types
    public static final Type INTEGER = new Type(Integer.class);
    public static final Type STRING = new Type(String.class);

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    private Type(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    // Object types are created by this constructor     
    public static Type of(Class<? extends Field> fieldClass) {
        return new Type(fieldClass);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return clazz.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        return clazz.equals(((Type) obj).clazz);
    }

    public Class<?> getValueClass() {
        return clazz;
    }

    // retrieve all possible Fields for given object type
    public Field[] values() {
        if(Field.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return clazz.asSubclass(Field.class).getEnumConstants();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's your updated enums:

```
public enum Address implements Field {
    HOUSE_NO("houseNo", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED), 
    STREET_NO("streetNo", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED), 
    LANDMARK("landmark", Type.STRING, Existence.OPTIONAL);

    String text;
    Type valueType;
    Existence exist;

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return valueType;
    }

    @Override
    public Existence getExistence() {
        return exist;
    }

    Address(String text, Type valueType, Existence exist) {
        this.text = text;
        this.valueType = valueType;
        this.exist = exist;
    }
}

public enum employeeSchema implements Field {
    NAME("name", Type.STRING, Existence.REQUIRED), 
    AGE("age", Type.INTEGER, Existence.OPTIONAL), 
    ADDRESS("address", Type.of(Address.class), Existence.REQUIRED);

    String text;
    Type valueType;
    Existence exist;

    employeeSchema(String text, Type valueType, Existence exist) {
        this.text = text;
        this.valueType = valueType;
        this.exist = exist;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return valueType;
    }

    @Override
    public Existence getExistence() {
        return exist;
    }
}
```

So in `validateData` you should accept the `Type` and get all the possible values for this type:

```
public boolean validateData(JsonNode data, Type type){
    Field[] values = type.values();
    if(values != null) {
        for(Field field : values) {
           ... // use field.getText()/field.getType()/etc. to validate
           // probably it's ok to call recursively here
           // validateData(data.get(field.getText()), field.getType());
        }
    } else {
        Class<?> clazz = type.getValueClass();
        // clazz is a simple type like Integer or String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` class represents a single enum constant of generic type; so `NAME`, in your example. What you want is something like:

```
public boolean validateData(JsonNode data, Class<? extends Enum> schema) {
  for (Enum<?> e : schema.getEnumConstants()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then you call

```
validateData(data, Adress.class);
```

Comment: It would be the easiest way to do this, but by doing this i am able to get enum constant in e but its properties are not available there because e is type of Enum<?>. like if i would iterate over employeeSchema i would get NAME but its properties text, valueType and exists wouldnt be available.